# ansible sh module does not report output until shell completes

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline

How can I see realtime output from a shell script run by ansible?

I recently refactored a wait script to use multiprocessing and provide realtime status of the various service wait checks for multiple services.

As a stand alone script, it works as expecting providing status for each thread as they wait in parallel for various services to get stable.

In ansible, the output pauses until the python script completes (or terminates) and then provides the output.  While, OK, it I'd rather find a way to display output sooner.  I've tried setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` prior to running ansible-playbook via jenkins withEnv but that doesn't seem to accomplish the goal either

```
- name: Wait up to 30m for service stability
  shell: "{{ venv_dir }}/bin/python3 -u wait_service_state.py"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ script_dir }}"
```

What's the standard ansible pattern for displaying output for a long running script?

My guess is that I could follow one of these routes

- Not use ansible
- execute in a docker container and report output via ansible provided this doesn't hit the identical class of problem
- Output to a file from the script and have either ansible thread or Jenkins pipeline thread watch and tail the file (both seem kludgy as this blurs the separation of concerns coupling my build server to the deploy scripts a little too tightly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html

## main.yml

```
- name: Run items asynchronously in batch of two items
  vars:
    sleep_durations:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
      - 4
      - 5
    durations: "{{ item }}"
  include_tasks: execute_batch.yml
  loop: "{{ sleep_durations | batch(2) | list }}"
```

## execute_batch.yml

```
- name: Async sleeping for batched_items
  command: sleep {{ async_item }}
  async: 45
  poll: 0
  loop: "{{ durations }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "async_item"
  register: async_results

- name: Check sync status
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ async_result_item.ansible_job_id }}"
  loop: "{{ async_results.results }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "async_result_item"
  register: async_poll_results
  until: async_poll_results.finished
  retries: 30
```

Comment: That's great.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to do what I want.  I want the ansible equiavlent of `tail -f` on the output.  Now, I see that async_results has an output file but I cannot access it.  async_poll_results has stdout but I cannot figure out how to loop through it.

Comment: I refactored my script from a simple monolithic execution of waiting on 12 items in parallel within the script to making it 12 script invocations using with_items and async.  It works great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"`What's the standard ansible pattern for displaying output for a long running script?`"

Standard ansible pattern for displaying output for a long-running script is polling [async](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling) and loop until [async_status](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html#async-status-obtain-status-of-asynchronous-task) finishes. The customization of the until loop's output is limited. See [Feature request: until for blocks #16621](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16621).

[ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner) is another route that might be followed.

Comment: Thanks. I'd be happy if I could just get the async_results task to perform the equivalent of a `tail -f` on async_results output file.  It seems like the data I want lives in async_poll_results but I cannot access it